# Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.34/ext/curl (The specified module could not be found.)

Tags: php, wampserver

I am trying to test a connection in my project. For this I am using the curl library. But encountered following error in my php error log:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.34/ext/curl (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.34/ext/php_curl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

I have checked my php config extensions and curl is enabled there. Also, have tried to check my php.ini file with extension_dir, it has been set to:
**extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.34/ext/"** (';' has been removed already to remove comments)

**extension=curl**
But still not able to resolve the issue. What should I try next?

Comment: So if you open the directory `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.34/ext` do you see the file `php_curl.dll`?

Comment: Yes, I have file **php_curl.dll** in the mentioned directory.